# Matching a delimiter separated values and omitting the first line with the headers

Tags: regex, csv

I am not well-versed in regex and I am matching from a .dsv file all the values separated by a semi-column, as follows:

```
(.*?);(.*?);(\d+.*)
```

However, I would like to skip the first line containing the headers' names. I have come up with something like this that matches the first line (or so I believe it does):

```
(?!\A)^.*\z)
```

I would like to combine somehow the two regex and make sure that the delimiter separated values matching will not involved the first line, but I am not really sure how to go about that.

Thank you very much for your help,

I.

EDIT:
 I am using Java syntax for regex

Comment: This is r? java? python?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java, R, Python? Also, are you parsing tabular data with a regex? Python has `csv`.

Comment: If this is in Python, check out the `csv` module You should be able to do what you need with that.

Comment: To clarify, I am using regex to modify flowfile content in Apache NiFi and it supports Java regex syntax. Hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: @innuendo You should put that up in the question. It would be better there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)(?!\A)^(.*?);(.*?);(\d+.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX0jK7/1)

The `(?!\A)` negative lookahead will make the `^` match all beginning of lines (not the whole string since `(?m)` inline multiline modifier is used) that are not the first.

Answer (score 0):

For the people using NiFi, you can also decide to run a script via [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html)  I have written a simple Groovy script that skips the first line in an independent step, after having matched the delimiter separated values:

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
    inputStream.eachLine { line, number ->
        if (number == 1)
            return
            outputStream.write(line.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```